# WINAPI GetRawInputData gives an error because of wrong parameters

Tags: c++, winapi, input

`GetRawInputData()` returns -1 (error) and `GetLastError()` returns 87 which is "The parameter is incorrect.", the first call to the function to get the data size succeeds but the second one, where I try to actually get the data, fails.

```
UINT DataSize;
if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)Message.lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &DataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == -1)
{
    Error("Failed getting raw input amaount\n");
}
RAWINPUT *Raw;
Raw = (PRAWINPUT)VirtualAlloc(NULL, DataSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (!Raw)
{
    Error("Failed to allocate memory!\n");
}
if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)Message.lParam, RID_INPUT, Raw, &DataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER) == -1))  // <-- Fails here
{
    Error("Failed getting raw input\n");
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis set incorrectly.

Comment: Side note: there is almost never a reason you'd need to call `VirtualAlloc` in normal course unless you're writing an allocator.

Comment: It's really unfortunate that the compiler doesn't warn about `sizeof(...) == -1`, for signed/unsigned comparison if nothing else. It definitely does have that warning in other situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@dialer mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197072/winapi-getrawinputdata-gives-an-error-because-of-wrong-parameters/69197231#comment122302238_69197072), the closing parenthesis are wrong in your 2nd call to `GetRawInputData()`:

```cpp
if (GetRawInputData(..., sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER) == -1))
```

You are comparing the result of `sizeof()` to `-1`, and then passing the result of that comparison (0 or 1) to the `cbSizeHeader` parameter (and then checking whether `GetRawInputData()` returns a non-zero return value), hence the "invalid parameter" error.

Which BTW, `GetRawInputDaata()` is NOT documented as using `GetLastError()` for error reporting, so you can't rely on that error code anyway when `GetRawInputDaata()` returns `-1`.

Change your `if` statement to close like this instead:

```cpp
if (GetRawInputData(..., sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == -1)
```